# Finding the path in a graph from A to B then back to A with a minimum of shared edges

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, programming

the problem is to find cycle from A to B back to A, so that the path B-A would use minimum edges from path A-B. The graph is undirected and can have cycles.

The paths don't have to be shortest, they just need to use the least amount of already used edges on the way from src -> dst. Basically, I always want to take different path back from dst to src, or at least with minimum already used edges on src -> dst.

Example

Graph is undirected, this is just for representing how the path goes.

[image]

Node 0 is src and node 4 is dst.

Solution is given bY

src -> dst = 0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

dst -> src = 4 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0

The least possible shared edges in this case is one (edge 2 - 3 )

I was thinking about finding all paths from A to B, then comparing each pair and then choosing the pair with least common edges, but there is probably better approach.

Comment: Please give a number of concrete examples. Does the length of the paths matter at all? Do you just want to find a cycle that includes both A and B?  Is the only situation where A->B and B->A may share edges the one where no such cycle exists?

Comment: Updated. Imagine it as you are travelling but you dont want to use the same path on the way back, if its not possible, then the path with least common edges.

Comment: Include a couple of small example graphs please.

Comment: You might be able to do something like the following (not sure about performance though): For each vertex pair $a,b$ where both directions are allowed replace the edges $a->b,b->a$ with $(a<->h,0),(a<->h,t),(h->b,a->b),(b->h,b->a)$ (the number after the edge indicates the weight, with $h$ being a helper vertex and $t$ being the total of all edges). In the new graph, your task should be the same as looking for the shortest path $a->b->a$ with no repeated edges. I'm not sure how you'd find the path $a->b->a$, maybe @Szabolcs' IGraph/M package has something that can help.

Comment: By example, I meant a few copyable examples in Mathematica syntax that can be used for testing, not an image.

Answer (score 7):

If the graph is 2-edge-connected then it's easy: find a path A->B, delete it, then find one B->A in the remaining graph.

```
verticesToEdges[verts_] := UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[verts, 2, 1]

findABCycle[g_, a_, b_] :=
 With[{path1 = verticesToEdges@FindShortestPath[g, a, b]},
  Join[path1, 
    verticesToEdges@FindShortestPath[EdgeDelete[g, path1], b, a]]
  ]
```

Demo:

```
SeedRandom[123]
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, VertexLabels -> Automatic];

a = 7; b = 8;
HighlightGraph[g, {findABCycle[g, a, b], {a, b}}]
```

[image]

If the graph is not bi-edge-connected, we must break it into bi-edge-connected components and do the operation on each component. The edges not in any of these components are called [bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)). These are the ones that may need to be repeated (if they fall on the path between A and B).

```
bridges[g_] :=
 Complement[
  Sort /@ EdgeList[g],
  Flatten[Sort /@ EdgeList@Subgraph[g, #] & /@ KEdgeConnectedComponents[g, 2]]
 ]
```

(Note: [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has the faster and more convenient `IGBridges`.)

Demo:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 
 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 8}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

(Note: I actually constructed this graph in IGraph/M using `IGShorthand["1-2-3-4-1,2-4,3-5-6-7-8-5"]`. So much more convenient!)

The bridge is 3-5.

```
bridgeList = bridges[g]
```

[image]

Let us choose A and B:

```
a = 1; b = 6;
```

Find a shortest path:

```
path = verticesToEdges@FindShortestPath[g, a, b]
```

[image]

Any bridges along the path will need to be traversed twice, no matter what.  We now separate the edges along this path into bridges and non-bridges, then determine at which vertices we are jumping from one bi-edge-connected component to the next.

```
ClearAll[bridgeQ]
bridgeQ[e_] := bridgeQ[e] = MemberQ[Join[bridgeList, Reverse /@ bridgeList], e]

segments = GroupBy[path, bridgeQ]
```

[image]

```
jumps = Level[segments[True], {2}]

(* {3, 5} *)
```

Find A->B path in bi-connected components:

```
directionAB = 
 verticesToEdges@FindShortestPath[g, ##] & @@@ Partition[
   Join[{a}, jumps, {b}],
   2
   ]
```

[image]

Now the opposite way:

```
g2 = EdgeDelete[g, Flatten[directionAB]];

directionBA = verticesToEdges@FindShortestPath[g2, ##] & @@@ Partition[
   Reverse@Join[{a}, jumps, {b}],
   2
   ]
```

[image]

Now put it all together:

```
Flatten@{Riffle[directionAB, segments[True]],
  Riffle[directionBA, Reverse /@ segments[True]]}
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[g, {result, {a, b}}, VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

---

Wrap it all up:

```
findAvoidingRoundtrip[g_, a_, b_] :=     
 Module[{bridgeList, bridgeQ, path, segments, jumps, directionAB, directionBA, g2},
  bridgeList = bridges[g];
  path = verticesToEdges@FindShortestPath[g, a, b];

  Set[bridgeQ[#], True] & /@ Join[bridgeList, Reverse /@ bridgeList];
  bridgeQ[_] = False;

  segments = GroupBy[path, bridgeQ];

  jumps = Level[segments[True], {2}];

  directionAB = 
   verticesToEdges@FindShortestPath[g, ##] & @@@ 
    Partition[Join[{a}, jumps, {b}], 2];
  g2 = EdgeDelete[g, Flatten[directionAB]];
  directionBA = 
   verticesToEdges@FindShortestPath[g2, ##] & @@@ 
    Partition[Reverse@Join[{a}, jumps, {b}], 2];

  Flatten@{Riffle[directionAB, segments[True]], 
    Riffle[directionBA, Reverse /@ segments[True]]}
  ]
```

Here's a demo on a larger graph. This time I will use [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) for constructing the example, simply for convenience.

Generate a nice graph suitable for this problem:

```
bigGraph = GridGraph[{10, 10}];
bigGraph = 
  SetProperty[bigGraph, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[bigGraph]];

IGSeedRandom[12]
g = IGTakeSubgraph[bigGraph, IGRandomEdgeWalk[bigGraph, 1, 100], 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Highlight the path:

```
a = 72; b = 56;
HighlightGraph[
 g,
 Join[findAvoidingRoundtrip[g, a, b], {a, b}],
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"
 ]
```

[image]

```
findAvoidingRoundtrip[g, a, b]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to construct a new graph `G2` where all edges that are already used in the forward path are given a large weight. Then we look for a return path in this new graph by using `FindShortestPath`. This shortest path will try to use as few of the high-weight edges as possible.

Start with a random graph `G` and a given forward path between `A` and `B`:

```
G = RandomGraph[UniformGraphDistribution[200, 300]];
A = 1;
B = 2;
forwardPath = FindShortestPath[G, A, B];
```

First, convert the forward path (list of vertices) to a list of edges, using Szabolcs' helper function `verticesToEdges`:

```
verticesToEdges[verts_] := UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[verts, 2, 1]
forwardEdges = verticesToEdges[forwardPath];
```

Next, construct a graph where the edges of the forward path have a large weight (here the square of the total number of edges in the graph `G`), all with lots of help from Szabolcs:

```
G2 = SetProperty[G, EdgeWeight ->
  Thread[Join[forwardEdges, Reverse/@forwardEdges] -> Length[EdgeRules[G]]^2]];
```

Notice that we're working around a bug here: quoting Szabolcs, "if when setting edge weights, an undirected edge is specified in the reverse direction compared to how it appears in the path, the edge weight will not be set."

Finally, compute the return path as the shortest path in this edge-weighted graph `G2`:

```
returnPath = FindShortestPath[G2, B, A];
```

Make a nice plot (with more help from Szabolcs):

```
returnEdges = verticesToEdges[returnPath];
Pforward = HighlightGraph[G, Style[forwardEdges, Green, Thickness[0.01]]];
Preturn = HighlightGraph[G, Style[returnEdges, Red, Thickness[0.005]]];
Show[G, Pforward, Preturn, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

All together in one function:

```
findDifferentReturn[G_Graph, forwardPath_List] := 
  FindShortestPath[
    SetProperty[G, 
      EdgeWeight -> Thread[Join[#, Reverse /@ #] &[
        UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[forwardPath, 2, 1]]
          -> Length[EdgeRules[G]]^2]],
    Last[forwardPath], First[forwardPath]]
```

Finally, according to the comments by Szabolcs we can use this function to construct a cycle that is optimally avoiding itself:

```
findEdgeAvoidingCycle[G_Graph, {A_Integer, B_Integer}] := 
  With[{fp = FindShortestPath[G, A, B]},
    {fp, findDifferentReturn[G, fp]}]
```

Try it out with the given example:

```
GG = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ {{0,2}, {0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {3,5}, {4,5}}]

findEdgeAvoidingCycle[GG, {0, 4}]
```

> {{0, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0}}

---

## Update: cycles aren't always optimal

While the return trips found by the above `findDifferentReturn` are optimal, the full cycles found by the above `findEdgeAvoidingCycle` are pretty good but not always optimal. Here is an example of a slightly sub-optimal cycle:

```
GG = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ {{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {3,0}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {4,5}, {5,6}, {6,2}},
       VertexLabels -> Automatic];
findEdgeAvoidingCycle[GG, {0, 6}]
```

> {{0, 1, 2, 6}, {6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 0}}

[image]

We see that the green forward path `{0, 1, 2, 6}` blocks the return path to some extent. The forward paths `{0, 1, 2, 6}` and `{0, 3, 2, 6}` would have been equivalent, but only the latter would have given rise to the optimal cycle `{{0, 3, 2, 6}, {6, 5, 4, 1, 0}`, which is one step shorter than what `findEdgeAvoidingCycle` found.

Comment: Nice idea!  It should be noted that theoretically it is not robust. Suppose that we have a cycle of size larger than 1000 (the weight we use), similar to this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2777.png  Of course, in practice this won't be an issue: just set a much larger weight, e.g. `10^10`.

Comment: Good point @Szabolcs , I edited the code to reflect this point.

Comment: @Szabolcs my code is quite clumsy, do you have any ideas for cleaning it up? Is there a way of constructing `G2` from `G` by re-weighting the edges instead of going through the whole reconstruction?

Comment: Well, it should be possible to make it much simpler because this syntax is supposed to work: `SetProperty[graph, EdgeWeight -> {edge1 -> 2, edge2 -> 3}]`. Except that it does not work if the edge is not given in the same order as it appears in the graph!   Thus this fails: `gr = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}]; SetProperty[gr, 
 EdgeWeight -> {3 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 10}]`  If I used `UndirectedEdge[2,3] -> 10` then it would work.

Comment: I should note that I did report this bug (and even have it on a list I keep for myself) but it's still not fixed despite its seriousness.

Comment: Thanks for the details @Szabolcs!

Comment: Here's a notebook with a simpler implementation and a workaround for the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bw3bc6qi4d22iuo/SelfAvoidingReturnPath.nb?dl=0

Comment: @Szabolcs may I use your notebook to clean up my code? It looks much better!

Comment: Sure, do with it as you wish.

Comment: Doesn't this optimize the return path after optimizing the forward path? I.e. it doesn't optimize the cycle as a whole, but in two steps

Comment: @LukasLang yes it only optimizes the return path for a given forward path, not the combination of the two (cycle). I constructed the forward path with `FindShortestPath` just as an example; could be anything though.

Comment: But then you're not guaranteed to find a combination of forwards and backwards paths with minimal overlap, right?

Comment: @LukasLang that's right. You'd have to optimize the forward and backward path together, which requires a new idea.

Comment: @LukasLang I think there's no problem. *All* paths between A and B will traverse the exact same bridges (see definition of "bridge" in my answer).  By definition, there is no alternative to traversing a bridge. If there were, it would not be a bridge (its removal would not disconnect the graph as there would be a path through the alternative)

Comment: @LukasLang The implication is that it does not matter which forward and which backward paths we choose: they *must* share the bridges, and no matter what the forward path is, the backward path can always avoid sharing any other edges (non-bridges).

Comment: @Szabolcs Right, I completely missed the fact that the graph is undirected (otherwise, it will most likely be more complicated) - the "example" given in the question is really confusing... (since it shows a weighted, directed graph while the question is about an unweighted, undirected graph). Anyway, thank you for pointing out the proper way to think about it :)